# Configure Make to fail immediately with bad target

Tags: makefile

I am launching multiple builds of a verilog compiler using Make.  I am only using Make to take advantage of the -j flag.  My file looks something like this

```
allfpga: fpga0 fpga1 fpga2 fpga3 fpga4 fpga5 fpga6

fpga0:
    cd fpgas/$(@)/build && $(MAKE)
fpga1:
    cd fpgas/$(@)/build && $(MAKE)
fpga2:
    cd fpgas/$(@)/build && $(MAKE)
fpga3:
    cd fpgas/$(@)/build && $(MAKE)
fpga4:
    cd fpgas/$(@)/build && $(MAKE)
fpga5:
    cd fpgas/$(@)/build && $(MAKE)
fpga6:
    cd fpgas/$(@)/build && $(MAKE)
```

And I invoke one of `make -j2 allfpga` or `make -j2 fpga0 fpag3 fpga5 fpga6`

However if there is a typo (such as in the command I gave `fpag3`), in the second make target, the system will happily spend minutes building, and then stop early.

My question, how can I get make to stop initially if some of the targets are not real ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no good way to get make to "pre-screen" all your requested targets.  Make can't know if a target is buildable until it tries to build it (for example it could be created based on some other target using a pattern rule or something).

However, you could do something like this:

```
ALLFPGAS := fpga0 fpga1 fpga2 fpga3 fpga4 fpga5 fpga6

# Get any command line goal which is not one of ALLFPGAS
unknown := $(filter-out $(ALLFPGAS),$(MAKECMDGOALS))

# If there are any, bail!
$(if $(unknown),$(error Unknown FPGA: $(unknown)))

allfpga: $(ALLFPGAS)

$(ALLFPGAS):
        cd fpgas/$@/build && $(MAKE)

.PHONY: allfpga $(ALLFPGAS)
```

Comment: thanks! just for reference, is `filter-out` a real command or that is left for me to build?

Comment: It's a standard GNU make function: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#index-filter_002dout